# Merging 2 largely unequal files using pandas or awk

Tags: python, awk

I have 2 csv that need to be merged, File1 is around `20gb` and other  only has `~1000` lines. Because of the large size I first iterate over bigger file and want to filter the bigger file (say file1) to a smaller file and then load/merge using pandas

`File1:`The bigger file is as below

```
col1,col2,col3
1,1,1491795901021327897
1,2,1491795901021342873
1,3,1491795901021347247
1,4,1491795901021351620
1,5,1491795901021356612
1,6,1491795901021361172
1,7,1491795901021366797
```

The smaller file is as below

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
val1,val2,val3,1,6,1412414141412414
val1,val2,val3,1,3,1434252352352325
```

One way I did was to create a single key from both files by doing `10*10**10(value at col1) + val at col2` and similarly in smaller file using col4,5. saving this values as a list and for each line in bigger file if value is present in list print that row. So finally a small filtered file is printed. Is there a better way to do this in python or using awk maybe.

Ultimate intent is to merge, but since 20gb cannot be loaded in pandas so I'm filtering my file and making it smaller. I'm sure there must be a better way to approach this.

Comment: Would you please paste the expected output?

Comment: what is the common key for merging, give an example using the posted data and what will be the structure of the merged file?  Are you filtering the large file based on the small file by matching `4,5`th fields to `1,2`?

Comment: `Are you filtering the large file based on the small file by matching 4,5th fields to 1,2? ` yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

by extrapolation, I think that's what you want

```
$ awk 'BEGIN        {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR==1        {h=$0; next} 
       NR==FNR      {a[$4,$5]=$0; next} 
       FNR==1       {print h,$3} 
       ($1,$2) in a {print a[$1,$2],$3}' small large

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col3
val1,val2,val3,1,3,1434252352352325,1491795901021347247
val1,val2,val3,1,6,1412414141412414,1491795901021361172
```

It should be easy to read but I can write explanation if I get feedback on my interpretation.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Could you please add your explanation aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ head f?
==> f1 <==
col1,col2,col3
1,1,1491795901021327897
1,2,1491795901021342873
1,3,1491795901021347247
1,4,1491795901021351620
1,5,1491795901021356612
1,6,1491795901021361172
1,7,1491795901021366797

==> f2 <==
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
val1,val2,val3,1,6,1412414141412414
val1,val2,val3,1,3,1434252352352325
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$4 FS $5]=$6;next} ($1 FS $2) in a {print $0 FS a[$1 FS $2]}' f2 f1
1,3,1491795901021347247,1434252352352325
1,6,1491795901021361172,1412414141412414
```

Explained -

Created key using `$4FS$5` from file `f2` and matching it with key of `$1FS$2` of  file `f1`, if `$4FS$5` of `f2` is matching with `$1FS$2` then print all contents from file `f1` along with the `$6` from file `f2`.